# Brocade FabricOS 8.2.2d: "rbash: setcontext: command not found" through SSH

Tags: ssh, storage-area-network, brocade

Context:

I’m writing a script that monitors all SFPs on a Brocade SAN switch and needs to iterate over all FabricID contexts.

When I log into a FabricOS 8.2.2d (also with 9.0.1) device through SSH then type:

`setcontext <FID>`

then the command behaves properly.

But when (as part of my script) I try to run the same command non-interactively via:

`ssh <username@hostname> setcontext <FID>`

then I get the following error message:

```
rbash: setcontext: command not found
```

What puzzles me is that other commands, such as `showsfp`, `switchshow` (that I intend to run after `setcontext`) work in both cases. I don’t understand what’s special about `setcontext` that makes it impossible to run non-interactively.

EDIT:
More findings using `command -V` (https://man.cx/command):

```
command -V sfpshow
sfpshow is hashed (/fabos/link_bin/sfpshow)

command -V setcontext
setcontext is a shell builtin
```

Could that explain why I can run the former but not the latter command through `ssh`?

Comment: For the record, I’ll be exploring this next: https://community.hpe.com/t5/hpe-eva-storage/hp-8-40-sanswitch-remote-commands/td-p/5204687

Answer (score 0):

From the ssh manual:

> If a command is specified, it will be executed on the remote host
> instead of a login shell.

A login shell will read some configuration files which usually set variables like `$PATH`, so when no login shell is invoked you usually end up with a different environment.

`rbash` indicates that on this machine a restricted bash is running, so the `-l` parameter of bash to invoke a login shell should work.

```
ssh <username@hostname> bash -l setcontext <FID>
```

Another option could be to use the full path to `setcontext`, since it's most probably the `$PATH` variable that is missing.

Comment: THANK YOU for you reply! Unfortunately, bash isn’t installed on the device: `rbash: bash: command not found`. I also don’t know the full path to `setcontext`, and rbash prevents the use of `/` (slash) anyway.